# Manually program the ISS freqs and tones into uv5r without chirp software

Tags: baofeng, radio-programming, uv-5r, chirp

Wondering if the programming data for communication with the iss can be manually programmed in to a baofeng uv5r without using chirp sofrware.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can.  Manual programming instructions can be found [in the manual](https://baofengtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/BaoFeng_UV-5R_Manual.pdf).